# Where to find the total daily compute time for an Azure web app

Tags: azure, web-applications

Azure web apps have plans that can restrict their daily compute time e.g.

```
F1
Shared infrastructure
1 GB memory
60 minutes/day compute
```

Where in the Azure Portal do I go to see the current and past days of compute time used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where in the Azure Portal do I go to see the current and past days of
> compute time used?

You can find this information by looking at metrics of your web application in Azure Portal. The metric you're looking for is `CPU Time`.

[image]

More information about it can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage.